# Tucking a CSS element into another

Tags: html, css, portfolio

Here again with another problem which is probably child's play for y'all.

If you don't understand, the heading I'll explain.

Basically, I have created a progress bar, which I am going to slap onto my portfolio website.

There's just one small issue that I am having. The #ability div works fine for the most part, but if you change the width property to 1%-3%, it overlaps the #bar div and really, I would like it to go underneath. Kind of hard to explain.

The current value of the width property is at 84%. Change it to 1%-3%. If you look at it, I'm sure you'll understand what effect I am trying to achieve:

http://codepen.io/DocRow10/pen/pgRXdv

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test Bars</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="bar">
    <div id="nil">
      <div id="ability">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
#bar {
    width: 400px;
    height: 55px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#nil {
    background-image: url('footer_lodyas.png'); /* Background pattern from subtlepatterns.com */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 7.5px;
    float: right;
}

#ability {
    width: 84%;
    height: 100%;
    background: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red , lime); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, red, lime); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, red, lime); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red , lime); /* Standard syntax */
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7.5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 7.5px; 
 /*  border-radius: 7.5px; */
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#bar` needs it's overflow set to `hidden`:

```
#bar {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Read more about the [CSS overflow property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) on MDN.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing, but I would put it on #nil as well

Comment: @John Keyes. Works great! I always wondered what the overflow property did and what it's used for. Thanks for the info and thanks for the help!

Comment: @ScottSelby I've now also decided to do that, too. I've just given it no border-radius and used overflow: hidden to tuck it in underneath. Thanks for your input.